# ALTER TABLE for ADO.NET sqlite for xamarin android

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, ado.net

I need to add new columns in my sqlite table. i have already read about ALTER TABLE and PRAGMA table_info, but as an indie (self-taught) developer, i do not know how to implement it. here is the code in my database class (which i got from Tasky sample app from xamarin):

```
public class YesDatabase
```

{
    static object locker = new object ();

```
public SqliteConnection connection;

public string path; 

public YesDatabase (string dbPath)
{
    var output = "";
    path = dbPath;
    // create the tables
    bool exists = File.Exists (dbPath);

    if (!exists) 
    {
        connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + dbPath);

        connection.Open ();

        var ccommandsc = new[] {
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Citems] (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, Cname NTEXT, Cnotes NTEXT, Ccat NTEXT);"
        };
        foreach (var commandc in ccommandsc) {
            using (var d = connection.CreateCommand ()) {
                d.CommandText = commandc;
                var j = d.ExecuteNonQuery ();
            }
        }

        //for first time users

         using (var f = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    f.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE [Citems] ADD COLUMN Cnumber NTEXT";
                    var l = f.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

    } else 
    {
        // db already exists, add column 

            connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath);
            connection.Open();
                using (var f = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    f.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE [Citems] ADD COLUMN Cnumber NTEXT";
                    var l = f.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

    }
    Console.WriteLine (output);
}


        Contact FromReaderc (SqliteDataReader r) {
    var c = new Contact ();
    c.ID = Convert.ToInt32 (r ["_id"]);
    c.Cname = r ["Cname"].ToString ();
    c.Cnotes = r ["Cnotes"].ToString ();
    c.Ccat = r ["Ccat"].ToString ();
    c.Cnumber = r ["Cnumber"].ToString ();
    return c;
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class YesDatabase
{
    static object locker = new object ();

    public SqliteConnection connection;

    public string path;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Tasky.DL.TaskDatabase"/> TaskDatabase. 
    /// if the database doesn't exist, it will create the database and all the tables.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public YesDatabase (string dbPath)
    {
        var output = "";
        path = dbPath;
        // create the tables
        bool exists = File.Exists (dbPath);

        if (!exists) {
            connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + dbPath);

            connection.Open ();

            var ccommandsc = new[] {
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Citems] (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, Cname NTEXT, Cnotes NTEXT, Ccat NTEXT);"
            };
            foreach (var commandc in ccommandsc) {
                using (var d = connection.CreateCommand ()) {
                    d.CommandText = commandc;
                    var j = d.ExecuteNonQuery ();
                }
            }


            //new column.
            using (var f = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                f.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE [Citems] ADD COLUMN Cnumber NTEXT";
                var l = f.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


        } else {
            // 

           connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath);
            connection.Open();

            //
            if (!CheckIfCnumberExists())
            {
                using (var f = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    f.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE [Citems] ADD COLUMN Cnumber NTEXT";
                    var l = f.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }


        }

        Console.WriteLine (output);
    }

private bool CheckIfCnumberExists()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + path))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA table_info([Citems])";

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int nameIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Name");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.GetString(nameIndex).Equals("Cnumber"))
                {
                    //conn.close();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN you_column_definition
```

So it could be

```
ALTER TABLE [Citems] ADD COLUMN Cother REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 10.12345
```

- [Citems] replaces `your_table`
- Cother is the column name
- Column type would be REAL
- constraints would be NOT NULL.
- the default value for the column would be 10.12345

Invoking the above (amended of course to suit) would be executed in place of `// already exists, do nothing.`

Note that there are restrictions as to the columns that can be added :-

> The ADD COLUMN syntax is used to add a new column to an existing
>   table. The new column is always appended to the end of the list of
>   existing columns. The column-def rule defines the characteristics of
>   the new column. The new column may take any of the forms permissible
>   in a CREATE TABLE statement, with the following restrictions:
>
> - The column may not have a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint.
> - The column
>     may not have a default value of CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE,
>     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, or an expression in parentheses.
> - If a NOT NULL
>     constraint is specified, then the column must have a default value
>     other than NULL.
> - If foreign key constraints are enabled and a column
>     with a REFERENCES clause is added, the column must have a default
>     value of NULL.
>
> Note also that when adding a CHECK constraint, the
>   CHECK constraint is not tested against preexisting rows of the table.
>   This can result in a table that contains data that is in violation of
>   the CHECK constraint. Future versions of SQLite might change to
>   validate CHECK constraints as they are added.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

> I have read that the command PRAGMA table_info is needed to prevent
>   errors in adding that column again when that app is re-opened

That's not really true you could check that the column exists by querying the **sqlite_master** table, which includes a column named **sql** that is the SQL needed to create the table.

For example (assuming the column to be checked is **Cother** ) then :-

```
SELECT instr(sql,' Cother ') > 0 AS result FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'mytable';
```

will return 1 row if the table exists with 0 if the column doesn't exist or with 1 if the column does exist.

If the SQLite version is less then 3.7.15 and therefore the **instr** core function doesn't exist

Then the following could be used:-

```
 SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'mytable' AND sql LIKE '% Cother %'
```

This would return a row if the column does exist or no rows if the column doesn't exist.

You'd use `PRAGMA table_info([Citems])` to return rows with columns :-

- cid
- name
- type
- notnull
- dflt_value
- pk

You'd then have to traverse the rows checking if the **name** columns contains the column, so is a little more complex to utilise.

> and the part where ALTER TABLE command can be written

As previously stated you'd do this if the database exists and therefore to replace the line :-

```
// already exists, do nothing.
```

Comment: hi. thank you for your response.  i have read that the command PRAGMA table_info is needed to prevent errors in adding that column again when that app is re-opened, as there is no "IF  COLUMN  NOT EXISTS".. i need to know that right syntax on how to use that pragma command, and the part where ALTER TABLE command can be written.

Comment: I have edited my post. i added the ALTER TABLE command inside the "if db already exists", as well as in "if db does NOT exists" ( create table, etc). newly added column is working fine.. however, i still do not know how and where to put the sqlite_master command. i know it should be used with if/else statement but i honesty have no idea how to do that.